# React native app stuck on splash screen in simulator

Tags: react-native, ios-simulator

When I try to run my react native app on the iOS simulator it often gets stuck on the splash screen.
restarting the simulator, restarting vscode,  deleting the app, and starting the packager again,  sometimes it will start and sometimes it won't. it's super finicky.

I can't figure out what's causing it, but it's really killing my productivity. I'm starting the packager and simulator using the `React Native : Run iOS on Simulator` command from VSCode's "React Native Tools" extension.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

**Answering for myself here:**

Can't say for sure, but it seems to be my work proxy causing issues. The App wasn't connecting to the packager at `http://localhost:8081/`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide more details? Are you using the lib https://github.com/crazycodeboy/react-native-splash-screen?
PS:It's the most used lib to do splash screen in React-Native.

I need to know this to give you a correct answer. But just a guess, I think you might be missing the code below:

```
componentDidMount() {
     // do stuff while splash screen is shown
     // After having done stuff (such as async tasks) hide the splash screen
     SplashScreen.hide();
 }
```

The method hide() hide the screen after the app starts.

Waiting for your feedback. Thx :).

Comment: No, I'm using the native splash. I set it up in Xcode `LaunchScreen.storyboard` it was working just fine up until a day ago, and now sometimes it goes away and sometimes it sits forever, and then the app will either load an old version from an old manually generated `main.jsbundle` or go to a blank white screen.

Comment: Why you don't use the react-native-splash-screen? It's much easier. It has a motive?  I never did without this lib actually, because it facilitates a lot to do this functionality.

Comment: I'll consider it. Wasn't focusing on the splash screen yet. Just threw something quick up. That wasn't the issue though. My app wasn't loading because of proxy issues.

Answer (score 0):

The issue may be caused by Flipper. [This solution](https://github.com/facebook/flipper/pull/1943/files) helped me

Answer (score 0):

"Erase all contents and settings" in sumulator also may solve the issue sometimes